# Cannot read property 'init' of undefined QuaggaJS

Tags: angular, quaggajs

I'm currently using QuaggaJs in Angular 2 with the quagga.d.ts imported into a component. However I get the following error when loading the page:

**Cannot read property 'init' of undefined**

The component has QuaggaJS setup as follows:

```
import Quagga from './quagga.d';

export class AddHomeComponent {


  Quagga.init({
    inputStream: {
      name: "Live",
      type: "LiveStream"
    },
    decoder: {
      readers: ["code_128_reader"]
}
  }, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return
  }
  console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
  Quagga.start();
});


constructor(private queryservice: QueryService) {



}

}
```

The script is also loaded:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quagga/0.11.6/quagga.min.js"></script>
```

I can't work out why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a compiler setting issue? I've tried all sorts..

Answer (score 1):

If you loading script manually through `<script/>` tag, you should use

`declare const Quagga: any;`

instead of

`import Quagga from './quagga.d';`

But, in this case, no typings for `Quagga` class will be provided.

Comment: I'm after using the typings because I'm using Angular 2 - Its wierd because the imported file works e.g. (when typing 'Quagga' it provides the methods with in the interface file such as init). However at runtime it is saying its undefined..

Comment: In this case you need to use `import Quagga from 'quagga';`, no `from quagga.d` and remove `<script/>` tag